# Reconstituting numbers in C/C++

Tags: c++

I have a stream of bytes that is being read in from a socket (little endian).
Can someone tell me why only the last one of the methods below gives the correct answer?
I suspect it's to do with the carry bit but not sure.  I've always found that when
printing binary data in hex form.

e.g.

```
printf("%02X", data);
```

it sometimes prints out funny values with 0xff in front.  The way to fix it seems to
be doing this.  This still occasionally happens when data is a char data type too:

```
printf("%02X", data & 0xff);
```

Heres a simplified example from what I was seeing with my byte stream.
Where bytes would be the stream of bytes I've read from the socket.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    union {
        unsigned int num;
        char bytes[4];
    } x;

    x.num = 500;
    printf("x.num=%u\n", x.num);

    unsigned int method1 = x.bytes[0] | (x.bytes[1] << 8) | (x.bytes[2] << 16) | (x.bytes[3] << 24);
    printf("method1 = %u\n", method1);

    unsigned int method2 = x.bytes[0] + (x.bytes[1] << 8) + (x.bytes[2] << 16) + (x.bytes[3] << 24);
    printf("method2 = %u\n", method2);

    unsigned int method3 = (x.bytes[0] & 0xff | (x.bytes[1] & 0xff) << 8 
                            | (x.bytes[2] & 0xff) << 16 | (x.bytes[3] & 0xff) << 24);
    printf("method3 = %u\n", method3);

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
x.num=500
method1 = 4294967284
method2 = 244
method3 = 500
```

Only the last extract is actually correct.
Is my method of building up the numbers the most optimal?  I also tried a `memcpy` to a variable but again that wasn't reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When signed datatypes are being cast into higher datatypes, the most significant bit is used as a sign bit.  You should have `unsigned char` in your union.  In your case 500 = 256 + 244 = 0x1f4 and the byte 244 has the most significant bit set, so when promoted becomes 0xfffffff4.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `unsigned char bytes[4]` in the `union`?  Without a signedness specification, you don't know whether your `char`s are signed or unsigned (depends on the platform and compiler) so it's not surprising that arithmetic on them gives peculiar results.

The `0xFF` you may have observed could likely be due to sign extension if your compiler does indeed decide to treat your "mystery char data" as signed rather than unsigned.

As a rule of thumb, when `char` is used to mean "a byte for further processing or display purposes" I would recommend always using `unsigned char` for definiteness -- I don't remember when the last time was that I really wanted a *signed* char!-)

Answer (score 0):

In a little-endian architecture, the number `500` (`256 + 244`) will be stored as:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 244(0xf4) |   1(0x01) |   0(0x00) |   0(0x00) |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

and, because you're using `char` on its own, the C standard doesn't specify whether it's signed or unsigned (it's implementation defined). In your case, it appears to be signed.

> Aside: sign extension happens in two's complement encoding when you load a "thin" data value into a wider one. Where the top bit of the thin number is 1 (indicating a negative number), this is extended to all higher bits in the wider type. The reason this is done is to preserve the nature of the number. For example, -12 in 8-bit is `0xf4`, in 16-bit is `0xfff4` and in 256-bit is `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff4`.

That means the `244` (`-12` or `0xf4`) will be sign-extended to `0xfffffff4`. That's likely to screw up your `|` and `+` solutions quite badly.

The values you'll get are:

```
x0       0xfffffff4  
x1<<8    0x00000100
x2<<16   0x00000000
x3<<24   0x00000000
```

Method 1 uses `|` so you end up with `0xfffffff4` (the other one bit in x1 are already set in x0 so it remains unaffected, and x2/x3 are all zero) which is `4294967284` as an `unsigned int`.

Method 2 adds them so that you end up with `0x1000000f4` which of course wraps, discarding the high byte and leaving you with `0xf4` or 244.

In method 3, the sign extension still happens but *before* you `&` it with `0xff`. It's that `&` operation that reverses the effect of the sign extension and turns your `0xfffffff4` back into `0xf4`.

As others have already mentioned, use `unsigned char` explicitly. This will prevent sign extension happening when promoting to a larger integral type.